# How can I hyperlink any pivot table across a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code for how to hyperlink a pivot table based on a single worksheet and single column. However, I would like to be able to use this code across an entire workbook for whenever there is a link in any of the pivot tables.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim selPF As PivotField
Dim strField As String

strField = "Invoice Link"

On Error Resume Next
Set selPF = Target.PivotField
If Not selPF Is Nothing Then
  If selPF.Name = strField Then

  ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink _
    Address:=Target.Value, NewWindow:=True
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Please can someone suggest how I can allow this across the entire workbook including new worksheets being added. Someone suggested this from a discussion board a long time ago but I cannot get it to work.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
' MsgBox Sh.Name ' MsgBox
Target.Address
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=CStr(Target.Value), NewWindow:=True
On Error GoTo 0
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should be able to use the same code from your first event handler as-is in the second one.  Only the sub header is different, but you only use the `Target` parameter and can ignore `Sh`